# Event triggered before data is inserted into page (After AJAX call)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This site (http://nelation.net/) loads pages by using AJAX and pushState. AJAX retrieves the contents of section#body and the path for the new CSS.

The following code sends the AJAX request, retrieves the new contents of section#body (page contents) and a new CSS path. Then it inserts those into the page, and after that it calls the "pageLoad" event - That's the event I believe is triggered too early.

```
function loadPage(url) {
    var target = document.getElementById("body");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
            target.innerHTML = "";
        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // Function to decode the new page
            var decodeEntities = (function() {
                // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
                var element = document.createElement('div');
                function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
                    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
                        // strip script/html tags
                        str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
                        str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
                        element.innerHTML = str;
                        str = element.textContent;
                        element.textContent = '';
                    }
                    return str;
                }
                return decodeHTMLEntities;
            })();

            var resultJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var page = decodeEntities(resultJSON.page);
            // Remove existing CSS and insert new one
            $(".page-css").remove();
            if (resultJSON.css != "none") {
                $("<link/>", {
                    "class": "page-css",
                    rel: "stylesheet",
                    type: "text/css",
                    href: resultJSON.css
                }).appendTo("head");
            }
            // Insert page contents, then trigger the pageLoad event
            $(target).html(page);
            $("body").trigger("pageLoad");
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
// Detect link clicks, and make AJAX calls out of them + pushState.
$("body").on("click", '[data-ajax="true"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // detect which page has been selected
    var newPage = $(this).attr("href");
    if (newPage != window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({path: newPage}, "", newPage);
    }
    loadPage(newPage);
});
```

The "pageLoad" event handler is found in this script. It re-executes most of the script, most notably the centerPlayButton_Featured() function if you're in the home page. That function resizes the overlay you see when you hover the image on the home page; It works fine when you load the page normally, but when you get to the page via AJAX it will not. The function is still executed (Logs to console), but I suspect it executes before the content is loaded properly into the page.

```
// DOES NOT RE-EXECUTE ON AJAX
function centerPlayButton_Featured() {
    console.log("centerPlayButton_Featured() just executed");
    var coverWidth = $("section.home-latest-release img.cover").width();
    var coverHeight = $("section.home-latest-release img.cover").height();
    $("section.home-latest-release div.cover-overlay").css({
        "height": coverWidth + "px",
        "width": coverHeight + "px"
    });
}

$("body").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("dropdown-text")) {
        if ($(e.target).siblings(".menu").hasClass("open")) {
            $(e.target).siblings(".menu").removeClass("open");
            $(e.target).removeClass("open");
        } else {
            $(".dropdown .menu, .dropdown .dropdown-text").removeClass("open");
            $(e.target).siblings(".menu").addClass("open");
            $(e.target).addClass("open");
        }
    } else {
        $(".dropdown .menu, .dropdown .dropdown-text").removeClass("open");
    }
});
// RE-EXECUTES ON AJAX
$("body").on("pageLoad", function() {
    $(function() {
        // HOME PAGE
        if ($("#body").children().hasClass("home-latest-release")) {

            centerPlayButton_Featured();
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                centerPlayButton_Featured();
            });

        }
        // MUSIC PAGE
        if ($("#body").children().hasClass("music-tracks")) {

            //...

        }
        // CONTACT PAGE
        $(function() {
            if ($("#body").children().hasClass("contact")) {

                $("textarea").bind("input", function() {
                    var offset = this.offsetHeight - this.clientHeight;
                    $(this).css("height", "auto").css("height", this.scrollHeight + offset);
                });

            }
        });
    });
});
$("body").trigger("pageLoad");
```

I appreciate any help/feedback. Go to the link to see more of the code, and tell me if you need to see the back-end. I apologize if the code is messy and comment-lacking. Thank you very much for the help.

Another problem I'm having is when you go to the music page, you may see all the dropdown menus fading out. Not as important as the main question, but help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

1. The `pageLoad` event is not triggered because it is bound to the window `load` event:

   ```
       $(window).bind("load", function() {
           $("body").trigger("pageLoad");
       });
   ```

   `load` happens only once during the lifetime of a window, and that time has long passed when an ajax request can even start. Trigger `pageLoad` directly.
2. `$(function () {...})` is executed once when the DOM has finished loading. Effectively, you are wrapping the code to be executed twice with the same event `load` which only happens once. Execute your setup code directly inside the `pageLoad` event handler. I'd write it like this:

   ```
   function pageSetup () {
       // HOME/MUSIC/CONTACT PAGE setup code
   }

   $("body").on("pageLoad", pageSetup);
   pageSetup();
   ```

Comment: It seems to have been called, judging by the console log.Now I removed it from the site, and the problem is not solved.

Comment: Have you removed all three lines? I meant to say, remove the first and third line of what I quoted and let the `$("body").trigger("pageLoad");` in.

Comment: Yes, I only removed the first and third lines. In fact, I had already tried it before submitting the question.

Comment: The code you provided contains no `pageLoad` event handler. Are you sure it is there, and that it will execute `centerPlayButton_Featured()`?

Comment: *facepalm* I managed to leave it out in the post because I have the code split up in different files on the back-end.  Sorry about that - You can see the handler there now (And I did mention in the post that the function runs, and properly logs to the console)